# Automatic convert to two decimal in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am assigning a value to other variable like this in flex web application.
this.X = _cord - width ;

In debugger value of (_cord - width) is coming 95.9995874156354. but after assigning it to this.X it automatically converts to 95.95.

Please help me on this.

Comment: if(!isNaN(n)) {
this.view.x = n;
}
Code is like this. Here View referring to UiComponent and n is decimal value.

Answer (score 3):

This is an inherent feature of coordinates in Flash player. The minimal value of a coordinate increment is called "twip" and equals 0.05. So, use something else than coordinate property to store values with desired precision.

Comment: How can I override this behavior ? I need this full digit 95.9995874156354 but it automatically converts to 95.95

Comment: I say you can't just for coordinates, but if you need precise value, use a custom var, say `real_x`, and address it everywhere instead of `x`, and also make a setter property for that var to automatically set relevant coordinate via `Math.round(value*20)/20`.

Comment: Can we use Mercator Projection here.